# Can I always extend a selfadjoint Operator in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

Assume that we have a self-adjoint operator $T\colon D \to D$ where $D \subset L^2$ is some finite dimensional subspace. Can I conclude that than a self-adjoint operator $S \colon L^2 \to L^2$ exists with $S=T$ on $D$ ?

Hope someone can help me.
Best regards,
Adam

Comment: Yes, I think. $D$ is closed, so you can take its orthogonal complement and define $S$ to be the null operator on it in such a way that $D$ reduces $S$. P.S.: Which is the same thing Sam does below, only that I have used more obscure words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $D$ is finite dimensional, it is closed. Let $\Pi$ be the orthogonal projection onto $D$, then let $S = \Pi T \Pi$. (Note that the first $\Pi$ is superflous, but makes it obvious that $S$ is self-adjoint.)

Comment: :D wow this argument is very impressive. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Take an orthonormal basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ of $D$, extend it to an orthonormal basis $e_1, e_2, \ldots$ on all of $L^2$ and set $S(e_i) = T(e_i)$ for $i=1, \dots, n$, and $S(e_i) = 0$ for $i>n$.